# Content 100% stretch

Tags: css, layout

Im trying to do layout that has header, content and footer. Footer must be bottom of the page(done). But my problem is how can I get content 100% strech between header and footer. When my content is empty, then I can't see that, but when I'm writing some word to html in to content div, like "hello", then the content is only so long than the content in content. I guess you can understand what I mean. 
Can somebody explain what is wrong in my css code.

Red is header, green is footer, cyan is content and blue is container. Problem is that Content does not cover the container area.

[image: t]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Praktika1</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="content"> 


     </div>

    <div id="footer">   
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
*{padding:0; margin:0;}

html,body{
 height:100%;
 }

#container{

 width: 1024px;
 position:relative;
 background-color:#cce;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height:100%; 
 }

#header{

 width: 1024px;
 height:100px;
 background-color: #CCC;
 }

#content{
  height:100%;
  width:1024px;
  background-color:yellow;
 } 

#footer{
 width: 1024px;
 height: 100px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 background-color: #ced;
 }
```

Comment: Highlight your code and click the `{}` button. It makes your code more readable to us.

Comment: I'd like to test on JSfiddle. Are you going to make me write the HTML code myself? `:)`

Comment: *"When my content is empty, then I can't see that"* Good to have a confirmation on that `:)`

Comment: Just saw your update - if you take a look at my answer, I'm pretty sure it's what you're looking for. There's a header, footer, and the content stretches between both of them for 100% of the page height, regardless of the amount of content.

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck. I spent a good amount of time yesterday figuring out a question similar to this.

http://andrew.x10.mx/rene/

html -

```
 <div id="container">
  <div id="header">
   <div id="header-content">
    Hai der. I'm a header.
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
   <h1>Content here</h1>
   <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-content">
     I'm a footer lol
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>                       
 </div>
```

css -

```
html,body  {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

 #header {
 background: #0f0;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 }

 #header-content {
  padding: 10px;
  }


#container {
 background: #ff0;
 height:auto !important; 
 height:100%; 
 position:relative;
 width: 1024px;
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height:100%; 
 }  

 #content { padding: 20px 10px; }

#footer {
 background: #f00;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 }

 #footer-content { padding: 10px; }
```

Comment: @Andrew Not interested in `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: @Andrew No, I was asking about using the above DOCTYPE instead of the one that you are using. You use the XHTML 1.0 Transitional DOCTYPE and I am asking why don't you use the new one.

Comment: @Andrew btw I edited out the irrelevant HTML code in order to make your answer more readable.

Comment: Ah. :P. I didn't realize it was a big deal. Updated it to a newer one, though. (You learn something new everyday, right? :D)

Comment: @Andrew Be careful though. Updating the DOCTYPE will break legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without the HTML, but I would try to add a min-height of %100 to #content

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be this:

```
#content{
    background-color:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    bottom:100px;
    width:100%;
}
```

You could use absolute positioning on all three parts of the page (header, content, footer):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/bBEJ6/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `margin-bottom: 0 px` could work?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is worded very poorly, but from what I can see you want your content to fill up 100% of your page, yet you have specified a specific width on your `#content` section by using the `width:1024px` property.

Try `width:100%` and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: The width is not the problem here. OP wants to stretch the content vertically.

Comment: No it wont help. I wanna height filled up 100% between header and footer.